# C fscanf data messed up

Tags: c, scanf

I am new to programming and is now learning C language. I had a problem when I try to read data from a file and store them in a char array.

My input is something like this:

```
Hayes,Darrell,Covey,Dasia,Hayes,Neftaly
Ashby,Angela,Chapman,Ebony,Ashby,Elliott
```

My code is like this:

```
while(1) {
int ret = fscanf(fp," %[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]",
    g_human_array[g_human_count].last_name, 
    g_human_array[g_human_count].first_name, 
    g_human_array[g_human_count].mother_last, 
    g_human_array[g_human_count].mother_first, 
    g_human_array[g_human_count].father_last, 
    g_human_array[g_human_count].father_first
    );
printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%d\n",
    g_human_array[g_human_count].last_name, 
    g_human_array[g_human_count].first_name, 
    g_human_array[g_human_count].mother_last, 
    g_human_array[g_human_count].mother_first, 
    g_human_array[g_human_count].father_last, 
    g_human_array[g_human_count].father_first,ret
    );
if(ret != 6) {
  fclose(fp);
  return READ_BAD_RECORD;
}
```

However, my output is messed up like this:

```
Hayes,Darrell,Covey,Dasia,hby,Neftaly
Ashby,6
6
,,,,,,0
0
```

human_t and g_human_array are defined like this:

```
 typedef struct human_struct {
  char father_first[NAME_LENGTH];
  char father_last[NAME_LENGTH];
  char mother_first[NAME_LENGTH];
  char mother_last[NAME_LENGTH];
  char first_name[NAME_LENGTH];
  char last_name[NAME_LENGTH];

} human_t;

human_t g_human_array[MAX_HUMANS];
```

Comment: how `g_human_array` is defined?

Comment: I don't believe your scanf input pattern is handling the newline character at the end of each line.

Comment: `scanf` doesn't care about lines (it treats a newline character like any other whitespace character). So when you ask `scanf` to get a string up to the next comma (with `"%[^,]"`), it will go right past the end of the line, and keep going till it finds the next comma. To avoid such problems, I use `fgets` to read a line, and `sscanf` to parse the contents of the line. That way, the `sscanf` can only use the contents of that one line.

Comment: Additionally: You do: read input, proccess input, check for error. Right(tm) way: read input, check for error, proccess input.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for helping!

Comment: What is `NAME_LENGTH`?

Answer (score 4):

`%[^,]` will match any string not containing a comma character. This means the newline character *will* be included in the string that it matches, so the last `%[^,]` will match the a string containing the last field of one line and the first field of the next line. Change it to `%[^,\n]` so it won't match across newlines.

```
int ret = fscanf(fp," %[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,\n]",
    g_human_array[g_human_count].last_name, 
    g_human_array[g_human_count].first_name, 
    g_human_array[g_human_count].mother_last, 
    g_human_array[g_human_count].mother_first, 
    g_human_array[g_human_count].father_last, 
    g_human_array[g_human_count].father_first
    );
```

Another solution is to use `fgets()` to read a line at a time, then use `sscanf()` to process it. But you still have to remember that `fgets()` leaves the newline in the buffer, so you have to remove it before processing with `sscanf()`, or put `\n` in the exclusion set just like I do above.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed my problem perfectly!

Comment: "%[^,] will match any string not containing a comma" is interesting as that specifier will go beyond a _string_.  Even a _null character_ in `fp` will not stop it.

Comment: @chux Yeah, but text files shouldn't contain null characters.

Comment: @chux I don't think there's any way to prevent that. You can't put `\0` in the exclusion list, because that will terminate the format string.

Comment: Yes _null characters_ in a _text file_ are usually a sign of  broken code or nefarious actors.  And we never need worry about [that](https://xkcd.com/1354/).

Comment: @chux But dealing with it is really complicated, not something a beginner can be expected to do. You essentially have to reproduce much of stdio.

Comment: @Barmar Perhaps not: `fscanf(fp,"%[^\n]%n", ...` is a way to read _most_ of the text line - including _null characters_.  I'll save deeper comments for a more relevant post.